# Fluent Validation, different validation for each item in a list in Asp.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I´ve been trying to find a way to validate items inside a list, each with different validation rules. I came upon Fluent validation which is a great library but I can´t seem to find a way to do validation for each item individually. I got a faint idea from this similar thread ([Validate 2 list using fluent validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786529/validate-2-lists-using-fluentvalidation)), but I´m not sure how to focus it how I want.

So I have this View Model:

```
 public class EditPersonalInfoViewModel
{
    public IList<Property> UserPropertyList { get; set; }
}
```

This contains a list of Active Directory properties. Each represented by this class:

```
   public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UserProperties Value { get; set; }
    public string input { get; set; }
    public bool Unmodifiable  { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The point is that, each AD property has different constraints so I want to specify different rules for each property in the list in some way like this:

```
   public class ADPropertiesValidator : AbstractValidator<EditPersonalInfoViewModel>
{
    public ADPropertiesValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.UserPropetyList).Must((p,n) =>
         {
              for (int i = 0; i < n.Count; i++)
                  {
                     if ((n[i].Name.Equals("sAMAccountName"))
                        {
                          RuleFor(n.input ).NotEmpty()....
                        }
                     else if(...)
                        {
                      //More Rules
                        }
                  }
          )

    }
}
```

Any ideas how to approach this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are approaching the validation from the wrong perspective. Instead of creating validation conditions inside your collection container class, just create another validator specific for your `Property` class, and then use that inside your `ADPropertiesValidator`:

```
public class ADPropertyValidator : AbstractValidator<Property>
{
    public ADPropertyValidator()
    {
        When(p => p.Name.Equals("sAMAccountName"), () =>
        {
            RuleFor(p => p.input)
                .NotEmpty()
                .MyOtherValidationRule();
        });

        When(p => p.Name.Equals("anotherName"), () =>
        {
            RuleFor(p => p.input)
                .NotEmpty()
                .HereItIsAnotherValidationRule();
        });
    }
}

public class ADPropertiesValidator : AbstractValidator<EditPersonalInfoViewModel>
{
    public ADPropertiesValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(vm => vm.UserPropertyList)
            .SetValidator(new ADPropertyValidator());
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh! I saw something similar in another post but thought that wouldn´t work.  Anyways this works perfectly! thanks!